# Index not working with Raven DB, how to debug it?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have an index:

```
public class FreeSearchIndex : 
    AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post, FreeSearchIndex.Result>
{
    public FreeSearchIndex()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
                       select new
                          {
                              Query = post.Tags.Concat(new[]
                                       {
                                           post.Title,
                                           post.Body
                                       }),
                              DatePosted = post.Date
                          };

        Index(x => x.Query, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);            
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public object[] Query { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and have method:

```
public List<Post> Filter(string freeSearch)
{
    IQueryable<Post> posts;
    var posts = documentSession
            .Query<FreeSearchIndex.Result, FreeSearchIndex>()
            .Where(x => x.Query == (object)freeSearch)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePosted)
            .As<Post>();                                 

    return posts.ToList();
}
```

and have unit test:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
                {
                    RunInMemory = true
                };

    store.Initialize();

    session = store.OpenSession();

    IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(FreeSearchIndex).Assembly, store);
}

[Test]
public void GivenFreeSearchPhrase_Filter_ShouldOutputFilteredPostsByGivenPhrase()
{            
    session.Store(new Post { Body = "universal answer to everything is 42" });
    session.SaveChanges();

    var posts = Filter("everything");

    Assert.AreEqual(1, posts.Count);            
}
```

And it fails, because query returns 0 posts. How do I troubleshoot this? Should I check generated query, is it possible to check how it indexed fields in store (which is in memory)?

Comment: Hm, but I don't want to WaitForStale in production, is there any way to tell session that all queries in it should wait for stale, that I could set that only for unit tests session? Can I check in debugger if it is in stale?

Comment: @oleksii - great, that listener helped, so if you wish, convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the indexer just didn't have time to process new data. You may get this test passing from time to time depending on the machine load, CPU and memory performance. To the best of my knowledge you would need to use some sort of `WaitForStale` solution in the unit tests.

I got this from a [RavenOverflow](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/blob/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Tests/RavenDbFactBase.cs) application on github

```
public abstract class RavenDbFactBase : IDisposable
{        
    public class NoStaleQueriesListener : IDocumentQueryListener
    {
        public void BeforeQueryExecuted(IDocumentQueryCustomization c)
        {
            c.WaitForNonStaleResults();
        }        
    }        
}
```

In production though, you do not use it and just bring stale data fast.